# Kendo Datetimepicker widget no minute gaps

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-datetimepicker

I am using following example:

http://dojo.telerik.com/AkIwo

When I select the time I get values like 12:00 / 12:30 / 13:00 - so half hour gaps.

Does anyone know how to define the "gaps", hence I want to change it to 12:00 / 12:15 / 12:30 / 12:45 and so on?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer (I was looking at the wrong doc, sorry)

```
$("#dateTimePicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    interval: 15
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the interval property:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // create DateTimePicker from input HTML element
    $("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
            value:new Date(),
            interval: 15
        });
    });
```

[Here's the Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AkIwo/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [interval](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/timepicker#configuration-interval) for time picker:

```
$("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker({
    interval: 10 //the interval you want to have between two time gap
});
```

Comment: Good answer, but try and use the "Code" tags - it makes life easier for people to read.